# User with 2 reputation completed reviews

Tags: discussion

I found [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10371299/comi-wolfsbrother) who, by my confusion and surprise, has a badge for reviewing posts, "Custodian".

*Custodian: Complete at least one review task. This badge is awarded once per review type*

It says the user was awarded this badge On September 16 at 16:45. He has one post with -1 votes, and no answers. How could he have possibly been able to get the privilege to review?

Comment: Post owners can approve/reject suggested edits on their own posts: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20875758 - they don't have access to the review queues outside of that though.

Comment: My posts have been edited multiple times, but I have never gotten a notification that someone edited your post and it needs to be reviewed.

Comment: If other users get to the review before you do it will go away and you will no longer see it. So if you want to see it you need to get to it fast.

Comment: If a user with edit privileges edits your post - you don't generally get a notification unless it's a "significant edit" - if it is - you'll get a notification that your post has been edited. If a user suggests an edit to your post - you'll get a notification regardless...

Comment: I see now, thanks Joe W and Jon Clements. So if I post a post and someone makes a small change I won't be notified. But if they change a lot of the post, like formatting and word choice, I would get notified? And if they comment a suggestion of an edit, no matter what I will get a notification?

Comment: @Marvin yup - that's it.

Comment: How does the system know what's a "small" edit and what's a "significant" edit?

Comment: @Marvin that I'm not 100% sure on... I think changes to any code blocks in the body count or a certain amount of changes (not sure how that's calculated) to the body of the post but don't think tag edits do... I think it's documented somewhere on here or MSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the activity tab of the profile page and look at the all actions->reviews section you will see that they have completed one suggested edit review. Looking at it closer it is for a post that they made which users are able to reject or accept suggested edits on.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/10371299/comi-wolfsbrother?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: Since I never have gotten the chance to approve my own posts' edits, I am assuming that everyone who has edited had 2,000+ reputation